# How SQLite index ID (or line number)

Tags: index, schema, primary-key, sqlite

SQLite is based on a flatfile, and store virtual tables in a flatfile (I think based on offset, correct me if I'm wrong). But how it index the Primary Key (ID), which I think is identical to line number.

When having SELECT with WHERE clause that ID = 99,001, how it skips 99,000 rows to read only the requested row. How is the process in a flat file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you're wrong.

There's nothing 'flat' in the SQLite database file; the file is internally split as pages, with trees and references between them.  A table doesn't' store records sequentially.

Check the [file format docs](http://sqlite.org/fileformat2.html)